# questions about how to make a star wars kind of game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a star wars game with HTML, CSS and JS. It should look a little bit like this game: https://www.gog.com/game/star_wars_xwing_vs_tie_fighter

Now I want to make it like a kind of game in which you have to shoot at enemy ships. for these ships I want to use this image:       http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/0/0a/TIE_Advanced_x1_starfighter.png/revision/latest?cb=20150310124250

Now her this is my questions:

How can I make it look like the ship in this image is getting closer to you? So that it appears in the distance really small and gets closer to you and becomes bigger, so that it looks like it is flying towards you?

I tried to use z-index but that did not work.

Also pls don't mind the code for I have been working on it for a long time and it finally works the way I want it to, but if it is a hinder in any further progress feel free to tell me what I need to add/change/remove or whatsoever.

Also I have been looking around on the internet how I could possibly make something like a star wars game but for example on this site the obly thing I could find related to star wars was how to make the crawling introduction but that is not what I am looking for:)

```js
Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
  'use strict';
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(this, max));
};
var url = document.location.href;
var n = parseInt((url.indexOf('n=') != -1) ? url.substring(url.indexOf('n=') + 2, ((url.substring(url.indexOf('n=') + 2, url.length)).indexOf('&') != -1) ? url.indexOf('n=') + 2 + (url.substring(url.indexOf('n=') + 2, url.length)).indexOf('&') : url.length) : 512 * 4);
var star = new Array(n);
var hyperspace = 0;
var lol = {}
lol.id = 'starfield';
lol.pr = {
  w: 1,
  h: 1
};
lol.zr = 256;
lol.timer = 0;
lol.spd = 1;
lol.rid = false;
lol.cvs = false;
lol.ctx = false;
lol.util = {
  isboolean: function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'boolean') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  isstring: function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'string') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  isobject: function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  isfunction: function(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  isempty: function(obj) {
    if (window.Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  isffx: function() {
    return (/firefox/i).test(window.navigator.userAgent);
  },
  copy: function(v) {
    return v.slice(0);
  },
  clone: function(v) {
    return Object.create({
      x: v.x,
      y: v.y,
      z: v.z
    });
  },
  sign: function(v) {
    v = parseFloat(Number(v).toFixed(1));
    if (v === 0) {
      return '&nbsp;';
    }
    if (v < 0) {
      return '';
    }
    if (v > 0) {
      return '+';
    }
  },
  random: function(n) {
    var i = 0,
      type, start, len, rnd = '';
    while (i < n) {
      type = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
      if (type === 0) {
        start = 48;
        len = 10;
      } else {
        start = (Math.round(Math.random() * 2) % 2 === 0) ? 65 : 97;
        len = 26;
      }
      rnd += String.fromCharCode(start + Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
      i += 1;
    }
    return rnd;
  },
  interpolate: function(from, to, n, i) {
    return from + (to - from) / n * i;
  },
  time: function() {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
  }
};
lol.i = function(id) {
  return window.document.getElementById(String(id));
};
lol.el = function(el) {
  return window.document.createElement(String(el));
};
lol.tn = function(txt) {
  return window.document.createTextNode(String(txt));
};

function $r(parent, child) {
  (document.getElementById(parent)).removeChild(document.getElementById(child));
}

function $t(name) {
  return document.getElementsByTagName(name);
}

function $c(code) {
  return String.fromCharCode(code);
}

function $h(value) {
  return ('0' + Math.max(0, Math.min(255, Math.round(value))).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

function _i(id, value) {
  $t('div')[id].innerHTML += value;
}

function _h(value) {
  return !hires ? value : Math.round(value / 2);
}

function get_screen_size() {
  var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  return Array(w, h);
};
lol.init = function() {

  window.addEventListener('resize', lol.resize, false);
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', lol.mouse.move, false);
  var e = lol.util.isffx() ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel';
  window.addEventListener(e, lol.mouse.wheel, false);
  window.addEventListener('keypress', lol.key, false);
  lol.viewport();
  lol.resize();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    star[i] = new Array(5);
    star[i][0] = Math.random() * lol.w * 3 - lol.x * 3;
    star[i][1] = Math.random() * lol.h * 3 - lol.y * 3;
    star[i][2] = Math.round(Math.random() * lol.z);
    star[i][3] = lol.x;
    star[i][4] = lol.y;
  }
  lol.anim.start();
};
lol.viewport = function() {
  var el = lol.el('div');
  el.id = lol.id;
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  window.document.body.appendChild(el);
  lol.cvs = lol.el('canvas');
  lol.cvs.id = lol.id + '-viewport';
  lol.cvs.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.appendChild(lol.cvs);
  lol.ctx = lol.cvs.getContext('2d');
};
lol.resize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth,
    h = window.innerHeight,
    el = lol.i(lol.id);
  lol.w = (w + lol.pr.w - w % lol.pr.w) / lol.pr.w;
  lol.w += lol.w % 2;
  lol.h = (h + lol.pr.h - h % lol.pr.h) / lol.pr.h;
  lol.h += lol.h % 2;
  lol.x = Math.round(w / 2);
  lol.y = Math.round(h / 2);
  lol.z = (w + h) / 2;
  lol.r = 1 / lol.z;
  el.width = lol.w * lol.pr.w;
  el.height = lol.h * lol.pr.h;
  lol.cvs.width = lol.w * lol.pr.w;
  lol.cvs.height = lol.h * lol.pr.h;
  lol.cvs.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
  lol.ctx.scale(lol.pr.w, lol.pr.h);
  lol.mouse.o = {
    x: lol.x,
    y: lol.y
  };

};
lol.anim = {
  update: function() {
    var c;
    lol.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    if (hyperspace === 1) {
      lol.spd = lol.spd * 1.015;
      lol.zr = lol.zr * 0.99;
      c = Math.round(lol.spd * 4);
      lol.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c + ',' + c + ',' + c + ',0.5)';
      if (lol.spd > 64) {
        lol.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
        lol.spd = 16;
        lol.zr = 256;
        hyperspace = 2;
      }
    }
    if (hyperspace === 2) {
      if (lol.spd > 1) {
        lol.spd *= 0.99;
      } else {
        lol.spd = 1;
        hyperspace = 0;
      }
    }
    lol.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, lol.w, lol.h);

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var test = true,
        x2 = star[i][3],
        y2 = star[i][4];
      star[i][0] += lol.mouse.p.x * 0.1;
      if (star[i][0] > lol.x * 3) {
        star[i][0] -= lol.w * 3;
        test = false;
      }
      if (star[i][0] < -lol.x * 3) {
        star[i][0] += lol.w * 3;
        test = false;
      }
      star[i][1] += lol.mouse.p.y * 0.1;
      if (star[i][1] > lol.y * 3) {
        star[i][1] -= lol.h * 3;
        test = false;
      }
      if (star[i][1] < -lol.y * 3) {
        star[i][1] += lol.h * 3;
        test = false;
      }
      star[i][2] -= lol.spd;
      if (star[i][2] > lol.z) {
        star[i][2] -= lol.z;
        test = false;
      }
      if (star[i][2] < 0) {
        star[i][2] += lol.z;
        test = false;
      }
      star[i][3] = lol.x + (star[i][0] / star[i][2]) * lol.zr;
      star[i][4] = lol.y + (star[i][1] / star[i][2]) * lol.zr;

      if (test) {
        c = 1 - lol.r * star[i][2];
        lol.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + c + ')';
        lol.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + (c / 4) + ')';
        lol.ctx.lineWidth = (1 - lol.r * star[i][2]) * 1.5;
        lol.ctx.beginPath();
        lol.ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        lol.ctx.lineTo(star[i][3], star[i][4]);
        lol.ctx.rect(star[i][3] - 0.75, star[i][4] - 0.75, 1.5, 1.5);
        lol.ctx.closePath();
        lol.ctx.stroke();
        lol.ctx.fill();
      }
    }
    lol.rid = window.requestAnimationFrame(lol.anim.update);
  },
  start: function() {
    lol.anim.update();
  },
  stop: function() {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(lol.rid);
    lol.rid = false;
  },
  pause: function() {
    lol.anim[lol.rid ? 'stop' : 'start']();
  }
};
lol.mouse = {
  p: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  o: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  click: false,
  move: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    lol.mouse.p.x = ((e.pageX - lol.mouse.o.x) / window.innerWidth) * 256;
    lol.mouse.p.y = ((e.pageY - lol.mouse.o.y) / window.innerHeight) * 256;
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  wheel: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta / 120;
    lol.spd -= delta * 0.1;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
lol.key = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 13:
      lol.anim.pause();
      break;
    case 32:
      hyperspace = 1;
      break;
  }
};
lol.init();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1
}
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#div {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">Galaxy Defender
  <br>Mohan Bloxs</br>
</footer>
```

Comment: This seems way to broad for this site, you're asking for a lot of general overarching questions. Ideally try these things yourself, then once you narrow it down to any specific problems, post them here.

Comment: I also think that when you get down to specific problems, don't post them all in one question. They may be related to the same project, but it will be more useful to future users if they see just 1 problem in a question rather than 5 at once.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you can see I created a running version as per the [help]. Please also visit the [tour] to see how and what to ask here. HINT: Too many questions in one post - search for collision detection for starters

Comment: I would recommend a text adventure or top down maze game first. Ask mustafa, fortune teller, and tons of other simple, single afternoon games will help you tremendously as you prepare for this project. Also, Rogue Squadron 3D (The best game of all time) is now available for newer versions of windows via steam. This tip is for morale more than anything.